# Does executeFetchRequest:error: return the same object instance every time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm new to `core data` and had a query.

If I call `executeFetchRequest:error:` to retrieve an entity from the context, and store this entity in a variable called A, and I repeat the process and store it the next time in a variable called B, will A and B refer to the same instance of the `NSManagedObject` i.e. will a change made to object A also be made to object B?

In addition, assuming I proceed to delete the entity from the managed object context, what would happen to these references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the **Core Data Programming Guide** section on [Faulting and Uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202-CJBDBHCB).  To quote:

> Uniquing Ensures a Single Managed Object per Record per Context
>
> Core Data ensures that—in a given managed object context—an entry in a persistent store is associated with only one managed object. The technique is known as uniquing. Without uniquing, you might end up with a context maintaining more than one object to represent a given record.

So, **provided you execute the fetches on the same context**, the returned results will point to the same instances.

When you delete an object, it is flagged for deletion until the next save operation, at which point it is deleted from the store.  If you retain a reference to it thereafter, CoreData will throw an error if you try to access it.  From the same document, in the section on creating and deleting objects:

> You can find out if a managed object has been marked for deletion by sending it an isDeleted message. If the return value is YES, this means that the object will be deleted during the next save operation, or put another way, that the object is marked deleted for the current (pending) transaction.

Comment: You are a god amongst men.

Answer (score 0):

the NSManagedObject subclasses are created and handled by the NSManagedContext by itself. It means you might possibly get the same instance of the NSManagedObject when you fetch them more time (but you don't know for sure). If you want to compare 2 objects, you should use some of your "isEqualTo:" implementations.

When you delete the object in that context, the contents of your properties will be removed. That means they will be set to nil if they are weak or they will point to deallocated memory if they are string. So it might happen that you app crashes when you try to access them via your properties(I've experienced that :)).

Answer (score -1):

Every time you fetch an object you are obtaining different instances. To check if represents the same object you should compare objectID properties (to check if they are pointing to the same record in the persistent store).
If you delete one from context, you can check if the other is in context using existingObjectWithId:error